Initialize a seeded rand.Rand using math/rand/v2
How do I go about initializing a seeded random number generator using the math/rand/v2 API.
Particularly I am puzzled how to create a Source in v2.
In v1, it is rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
but in v2 there is no NewSource function.
I know I can seed a PCG rng, but it does not have the Shuffle method, which I need.

A rand.PCG is a rand.Source, as is a rand.ChaCha8. Use either of those.

@JimB That worked, thanks!
